# Mathematica: Label specific vertices in GraphPlot

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, version-7

How can I label particular vertices in GraphPlot? And have the arrows space out accordingly, for the width of the label?

I have Mathematica 7, but I think this question applies to all versions.

[image: Mathematica Graph Plot]

Edit:
I posted the above graph so you can see label overlap might kill whatever information the graph is displaying.

For simplicity, lets do a mock graph:

Generate the Data:

```
data = #[[1]] -> #[[2]] & /@ Partition[RandomInteger[10, 100], 2]
```

Plot the Graph:

```
GraphPlot[data, EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Red, {Arrowheads[Small], Arrow[#1, .07]}} &)]
```

Gives something like:

[image: Random GraphPlot]

If I wanted to explicitly label "1" and "5", this is where I'm completely lost:

I'm happy with the ugly yellow boxes for now:

```
GraphPlot[data,EdgeRenderingFunction->({Red,{Arrowheads[Small],Arrow[#1,.07]}}&), VertexLabeling->True]
```

[image: yellow box, on all labeling]

But you can see it can be problematic if I labeled every point in the first graph. I wish the `VertexLabelingFunction` help pages was a bit more thorough, all it seem it do is some sort of rule based, rather than explicit labels. I'm thinking it'll be some `VertexLabelingFunction -> (If[#1 == "1" || #1 == "5", Text[#1]])&` But that always gives me an error.

Comment: Are you sure you want a mathematica solution and not one in ruby? ;)

Comment: Write custom vertex and edge rendering functions and pass them to GraphPlot. There are significant differences in the arguments to the `VertexRenderingFunction` and `GraphRenderingFunction` between Mathematica 7 and 8.  Do you prefer an answer for 7 or for 8?

Comment: Prefer 7 please. Wasn't sure there were that many differences between the languages outside of the whole 'free form typing' thing.

lol yoda, I'm very new to ruby, but I find it pretty intriguing. But I've been a mathematica hobbyist for a couple years now. Plus plotting in mathematica is sexy.

Comment: Please recheck your understanding of "sexy" with a good doctor :).

Comment: Perhaps you should include the code for a simple graph as an example. The GraphPlot above cannot be used by answerers and is therefore less useful as an illustration. By the way, a considerable proportion of the Mathematica community that stalked this tag has moved to the dedicated Mathematica site at Mathematica.stackexchange.com. You might want to consider moving as well.

Comment: Have you tried `VertexRenderingFunction`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately, I am completely new on `VertexRenderingFunction`. All my approaches are simplistic, and wrong. Even if I manage to get the text to display, I'm sure it'll overlap on the arrows. Didn't know about stackexchange, looks great, thanks, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 8):

You could do something like this. It's an adaptation of the first example in the documentation for `VertexLabelingFunction` where I used an `If` statement to determine whether a vertex should be labeled or not. The function `offset` is just a helper function to determine by what amount the arrows should be shortened based on whether they end or start at a labeled vertex or not and `lblLst` is the list of vertices you want to label:

```
lblLst = {1, 5, 10};

offset[lblLst_, edge : {e1_, e2_}] := If[MemberQ[lblLst, #], .13, .07] & /@ edge

GraphPlot[data, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction ->
  ({Red, Arrowheads[Small], Arrow[#1, offset[lblLst, #2]]} &),

 VertexRenderingFunction -> (If[MemberQ[lblLst, #2],
     {White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[#, .1], Black, Text[#2, #1]},
     {Blue, Point[#1]}] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: try this data(http://juggernautmotorsports.ca/work/code/mathematica/data) and you'll see what I mean. With `lblLst = {"jshamess", "BuzzBuzzHome", "Urban_Toronto", 
  "RealNet_Canada", "Urbanation", "BrianPersaud"}`. To load into file, DL the data from link, then `GraphPlot[<< "~/data",
 EdgeRe...` if data is in your home dir, or `<<"~/Downloads/data"` if it's in your Downloads folder. Thanks so much though, it's a huge leap forward.

Comment: How can you keep your Tooltip labeling using an Vertex Rendering Functinon?